# How to change the color and radius of button with single drawable file?

Tags: android, button, colors, drawable, radius

I want to change the Color and Radius of my button with single drawable file. In the Drawable file I select the color and radius for my button.But when I call it in my MainActivity.XML it is only changing the radius of Button not the color of my Button Please Help.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape  android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
```

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="LOGIN"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/button" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Application Theme from `MaterialComponents` to `AppCompat` for example make it `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: @TamoorMalik Not at all my friend. You are Wellcome

Answer (score 0):

You should use ImageButton instead of Button.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton